# Unable to update Eclipse Indigo for ADT plugins

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, updates

I am using Eclipse Indigo to develop android apps. But when I updated android sdk and restarted it, it prompt me to update ADT to the latest version. So I check for updates but I am  getting this error while updating:

*Error reading update site http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/%7Echeckout%7E/pde-ui-home/samples/.
The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.*

I searched the web and found some that it is arising because they shifted their samples repository to GIT from CVS. But I was not able to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Indigo release (3.7) is an older version of eclipse. Maybe that has something to do with it? (just a guess) Juno (4.2) is the newest release of eclise, I'm sure it wouldn't hurt to try

[Eclipse Juno Release Info Page](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/)

hope this helps